# Use alternative browser with Subversion URLs

Tags: svn, atlassian-fisheye

We have subversion setup with http access through apache at http ://svn.local/ This provides access through svn clients and the standard svn repository browser. We also have a separate repository browser installed at http ://svn-browser.local/ (fisheye in this case).

Is it possible to change the subversion/apache server so that browser requests are redirected to the subversion browser, but requests from svn clients go to the subversion server? Essentially, I'd like to use a single URL to identify a resource in both svn clients and the svn browser and be able to copy the url from a svn client into a web browser to have the enhanced functionality provided by the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be a very hacky answer, but -- user agent and mod_rewrite. Practically every browser and bot claims to be `Mozilla` while SVN claims to be just `SVN` followed by version information. If you need help with mod_rewrite http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html helps it has a user agent based solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the fact that actual HTTP requests from svn client start with `/!svn`.

Cool idea, by the way.